# ListView not responding

Tags: android, android-layout

i have a problem with a listView that is shown deep under many layers of other layouts.
here the code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TabHost
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_weight="12"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1">
            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:minWidth="25px"
                android:minHeight="25px"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout5"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:layout_weight="1">
                <ScrollView
                    android:minWidth="25px"
                    android:minHeight="25px"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
                    android:scrollbars="none">
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:minWidth="25px"
                        android:minHeight="25px"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2">
                        <LinearLayout
                            android:orientation="vertical"
                            android:minWidth="25px"
                            android:minHeight="25px"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:id="@+id/linearLayout3">
                            <TextView
                                android:text="@string/UTlbEqID"
                                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:id="@+id/lbEqID" />
                            <TextView
                                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:id="@+id/lbEqIDVar"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                                android:hint="wie sieht dass denn aus?" />
                            <TextView
                                android:text="@string/UTlbEqDesc"
                                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:id="@+id/lbEqDesc"
                                android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />
                            <TextView
                                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:id="@+id/lbEqDescVar"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                                android:hint="wie sieht dass denn aus?" />
                            <TextView
                                android:text="@string/UTlbTaskID"
                                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:id="@+id/lbTaskID"
                                android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />
                            <TextView
                                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:id="@+id/lbTaskIDVar"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                                android:hint="wie sieht dass denn aus?" />
                            <TextView
                                android:text="@string/UTlbTaskDesc"
                                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:id="@+id/lbTaskDesc"
                                android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />
                            <TextView
                                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:id="@+id/lbTaskDescVar"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                                android:hint="wie sieht dass denn aus?" />
                            <TextView
                                android:text="@string/UTlbTaskDate"
                                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:id="@+id/lbTaskDate"
                                android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />
                            <TextView
                                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:id="@+id/lbTaskDateVar"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                                android:hint="wie sieht dass denn aus?" />
                        </LinearLayout>
                        <LinearLayout
                            android:orientation="vertical"
                            android:minWidth="25px"
                            android:minHeight="25px"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                            android:id="@+id/linearLayout4">
                            <FrameLayout
                                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                                android:minWidth="25px"
                                android:minHeight="25px" />
                        </LinearLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </ScrollView>
            </LinearLayout>
            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="bottom" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>
</LinearLayout>
```

well, the exact code of the listview, shwon via the tabcontent is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:isScrollContainer="true">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:minWidth="25px"
            android:minHeight="25px"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
            android:layout_height="57dp">
            <Button
                android:text="@string/EmpTbtnEmploAdd"
                android:id="@+id/btnEmploAdd"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
            <Button
                android:text="@string/EmpTbtnEmploDel"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/btnEmploDel"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <ListView
            android:minWidth="25px"
            android:minHeight="25px"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/lvEMPT"
            android:layout_height="162px"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:isScrollContainer="true"
            android:divider="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:dividerHeight="1px" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

my problem is, that this list won't expand itself neither to the parent if i set its height attribute to fill_parent or match_parent nor to the size of all its items. it won't even scroll whatever i do. The only thing it does ist responding to an click event, at least the only item shown(of 10) is getting hilightend blue (seems to be the main colour of an sgs+) as i click it, but there is no code behind that yet.

the list should resize itself at least to parent or to the number of items it has, up to a certain point, where it should be scrollable then.

how is it possible to get that thing work that way?

ps: you may wonder about the 162px, i tried to resize that damn thing by code but the height attribute is read only...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `ListView` inside `ScrollView`. `ListView` can't be used in such way.

By the way, your layout is extremely inefficient - nested layouts are bad for perfomance. Consider using `RelativeLayout` instead of multiple `LinerLayout`

Comment: well i removed the scroll view, now the listView is scrolling and i was able to remove many layers, but will try the relative Layout. well... is it possible that the list expands further than there is space on the screen, like it should've done with the scroll view? i need the space down there, because there will be many items to be seen (maybe up to over a hundred at a time), and only be able to see up to two and a half at any given time is well... not very suitable

Comment: @EaranMaleasi `ListView` already works in this way. Or I'm not getting your problem.

Comment: na, it only expands to the the limit of its parents, but i have to get more space.

Comment: @EaranMaleasi no it is not (well it is expands to the limit of its parents, but `ScrollView` works in the same way). You should read how `ListView` works. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html

Comment: well all that I've seen there was much bla bla about loaders and an example with loaders. well, what i want is, that not the contents in the list expand further than the list View itself, i want the listView itself to expand further, than it can be shown... in the ScrollView it was possible, to insert an multiline EditText, which expanded further than the bounds of the layout, allowing me to scroll the whole layout down. and thats what i want.

Comment: @EaranMaleasi I'll repeat - it is already work in that way. Main difference between `ListView` and `ScrollView` is that `ListView` caches used views (which are loaded through `ListAdapter`) and `ScrollView` not. Are you sure that you need `ListView`? Probably you are looking for `ScrollView`.

Comment: i've solved it on another way, just by reorganizing the layout, now there is enough space. thanks for your answer